# NRules Issue: Rule Matching on super class dont work

Tags: nrules

i have a class C, which inherits from A.
Now i want to write a Rules, that matches on type A. So I tried the following code:

```
 public class tmp : Rule
{
    public override void Define()
    {
        A t = null;
        When().Match<A>(() => t);
        Then().Do(ctx => Console.WriteLine("test"));
    }
}
```

But this don't work. Can anyone explain, how I can fix this issue?
This doesnt work.

Best regards

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the code - definition of A and C, code where you compile rules into session, where you instantiate and insert the fact into the session and call Fire method?

Answer (score 1):

Matching on the parent class definitely does work in NRules. Here is a full working example.

```cs
public class A
{ }

public class C : A
{ }

public class TestRule : Rule
{
    public override void Define()
    {
        A fact = null;

        When()
            .Match(() => fact);
        Then()
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("Test"));
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var repo = new RuleRepository();
        repo.Load(x => x.From(xx => xx.AssemblyOf<Program>()));

        var factory = repo.Compile();
        var session = factory.CreateSession();

        session.Insert(new C());
        session.Fire();
    }
}
```

If you post the rest of your code, I can update this answer and show where the issue is.
Maybe you didn't insert the fact into the session, or maybe you didn't call the `Fire` method, or maybe you didn't include the rule when compiling the session factory.